# How to use python to create an app that you can use to open other files?

Tags: python, file

I am working on a project that allows you to create your own key shortcuts. The program needs to import a list of settings from another file, I have called these .pog files. Here is an example of a .pog file:

```
q||tap``ctrl`l|type`docs.google.com`enter`
a||tap``alt``tab`
z||quit
```

Here is main.py, as you can see I just import the .pog file to use it in my program

```
import monitor

with monitor.Monitor.from_file('demo.pog') as monitor:
  while monitor.running:
    'vibe in the background'
```

This is a pain to work with as every time I want to use a different set of shortcuts, I have to either rewrite demo.pog, or open main.py and change the directory of the .pog file it opens.

I would like to be able to right click on a .pog file and choose "open with main.py" the same way I would open a file with notepad or idle. Is there a way to set up a python file to be able to open other files like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to turn the python file into an executable using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). It will basically let you turn your `.py` file into a `.exe` on windows or plain binary on macos/linux.

### Basic pyinstaller use

The easiest way to do this is to install it:

`pip install pyinstaller`

Then run it over your file specifying that you want the output to be a single `.exe` file:

`pyinstaller --onefile yourfile.py`

There will be a folder inside wherever `yourfile.py` is called `/dist` and inside there will be the `.exe` or binary file.

### Getting the binary to be recognized for the extension

From there there's system-level ways to register binary programs as extension handlers that differ per OS.

#### Windows

With windows you can just right-click a file and select `Open With...`:
[image: Open With Context menu]

then scroll down to find `Look for another app on this PC`and browse to the new `.exe` file you created with Pyinstaller:

[image: Set default application extension handler]

To update the file just replace the `.exe` file with new builds of your script using the same pyinstaller method from above.

#### MacOS

I don't own a mac, but here are the first two guides I found on google:

- https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/how-to-manage-file-associations-in-macos/
- https://www.macworld.com/article/231567/change-default-app-macos.html

#### Linux

This changes by every different distribution of linux. I would recommend going to a community forum to ask this, because even across similar distributions there are custom implementations to make this "easier"